# A gaussian tail estimation

Tags: probability, inequality, distribution-tails

In the proof of minmax bound for multi-arm bandits, it refers an inequality $$\frac{\exp \left(-x^{2}\right)}{x+\sqrt{x^{2}+2}} \leq \int_{x}^{\infty} \exp \left(-t^{2}\right) d t \leq \frac{\exp \left(-x^{2}\right)}{x+\sqrt{x^{2}+4 / \pi}},x\ge0.$$ However, I've not found the proof in its reference and I didn't find it trivial. It is a tight bound I think. Can anyone share an idea?

Answer (score 2):

It's from a less well-known (I think) inequality about Gaussian Mills' ratio $M(x)\equiv e^{x^{2}}\int_{x}^{\infty}e^{-t^2}dt$ that for $x\geq0$,
$$\frac{1}{x+\sqrt{x^{2}+2}}<M(x)\leq\frac{1}{x+\sqrt{x^{2}+4/\pi}}. $$
The upper bound is tight while the lower bound is not. For the proof of a more general version of this inequality, see [W. Gautschi (1959b). *Some elementary inequalities relating to the gamma and incomplete gamma function*. J. Math. Phys. 38(1), pp. 77–81.](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1002/sapm195938177)